# Family tree... the genealogy

Tags: word-request

What do we call a man who begins a family. Do we call him an antecedent or great-grand father or ancestor, a lineal antecedent? Or what?
Such as, there is a family Richard. Now, the family got its roots from a man's offspring, Richard. What would we call Richard?

Comment: what do you mean by "begin a family"... Does Richard have a mother and father?

Comment: I mean a genealogy.

Comment: I mean the first man to begin a genealogy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the word **patriarch**, and at least some people will know what you mean. The patriarchs from the Bible were the first men whose descendents eventually became the nation of Israel.